# Find the largest numeric string from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have one list. I want to find max number but I got the wrong max number
I try below code

```
list1=['400160', '400161', '400162', '400163', '400164', '400165', '400166', '400167', '400168', '400169', '400170', '400171', '400172', '400173', '400174', '400175', '400176', '400177','99990', '99991', '99992', '99993', '99994', '99995', '99996', '99997', '99998', '99999']
list1.sort() 

#printing the last element 
print("Largest element is:", list1[-1])
#print max(list1)
```

my output as below:-

```
print("Largest element is:", list1[-1])
('Largest element is:', '99999')
```

but its wrong. how to find max number

Comment: It is not wrong. You are comparing strings, and `'99999'` comes after `'400177'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are comparing a list of strings, and the sort happens lexicographically, and if you sort that way, `'99999'` is the maximum lexicographically

Hence you need to convert the list of strings to a list of numbers first, then use [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) builtin to find the maximum.

Sorting the list to find the maximum is perhaps an overkill.
Sorting + maximum finding will be `O(n*logn)` whereas just finding the maximum is `O(n)`

```
In [40]: list1=['400160', '400161', '400162', '400163', '400164', '400165', '400166', '400167', '400168', '400169', '400170', '400171', '400172', '400173', '400174', '400175', '400
    ...: 176', '400177','99990', '99991', '99992', '99993', '99994', '99995', '99996', '99997', '99998', '99999']                                                                   

In [41]: list1 = list(map(int,list1))                                                                                                                                               

In [43]: max(list1)                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[43]: 400177
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `key` argument of `max` is another sensible approach.

```
max(list1, key=int)
# '400177'
```

Note that you DO NOT have to sort `list1` beforehand, finding the max should never be worse than O(N) in complexity in the worst case.

The reason for your current output is because you call `list.sort` on a list of strings. `sort` will compare strings lexicographically by default, and '9' > '4'.

Comment: Interesting approach :) Find the maximum without converting the list

Answer (score 2):

Convert `strings` to `int` and find the `max` :

```
max(map(int, list1))

400177
```

Answer (score 2):

Should use `map` and `max`. Like this:

```
list1=['400160', '400161', '400162', '400163', '400164', '400165', '400166', '400167', '400168', '400169', '400170', '400171', '400172', '400173', '400174', '400175', '400176', '400177','99990', '99991', '99992', '99993', '99994', '99995', '99996', '99997', '99998', '99999']
print(max(map(int, list1)))
```

Output:

```
>>>python3 test.py 
400177
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
max(map(int, list1))
```

you have to convert your items from `str` to `int` first. I did that here with `map(int, list1)` which applies `int()` to every item in `list1`.

Answer (score 1):

print "Largest element is:", max(map(int,list1))